# Redirect sub directory name as a parameter to other site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a rewrite rule such that when user visits:

```
http://sub.site.com/embed/123
http://sub.site.com/embed/124
```

he should be redirected to:

```
http://embed.cbplayer/player.swf?config=http://sub.site.com/cbplayer/embed_player.php?vid=123
http://embed.cbplayer/player.swf?config=http://sub.site.com/cbplayer/embed_player.php?vid=124
```

Every thing will be same in all requests except the last subdirectory `123` and `124`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/embed/([0-9]+) http://embed.cbplayer/player.swf?config=http://sub.site.com/cbplayer/embed_player.php?vid=$1
```

Or if you would rather use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?embed/([0-9]+) http://embed.cbplayer/player.swf?config=http://sub.site.com/cbplayer/embed_player.php?vid=$1 [L,R=301]
```